# How to save new imagebutton picture and load newly created imagebutton image on relaunch

Tags: android, android-fragments, save, load, android-imagebutton

I am trying to reload the image that I get from either my gallery or camera in the imagebutton once the app closes

I have tried saving it to a file and loading from that file but I cannot get it to work.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    ImageButton profilePic;

    Drawable myDrawable;
    Bitmap bitmap ;




    String photoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);



       profilePic = (ImageButton) root.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        myDrawable = profilePic.getBackground();
        bitmap = drawableToBitmap(myDrawable);


// set up listener on ImageButton to load method changeProfilePicture() when user clicks profilePic
        profilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                changeProfilePicture();
            }
        });


        int Permission_All = 1;

        String[] Permissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        if(!hasPermissions(getActivity(), Permissions)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), Permissions, Permission_All);

        }


       loadImageFromStorage(photoPath);
        return root;

    }


    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        loadImageFromStorage(photoPath);

    }

    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();

    }

    public void onPause() {

        super.onPause();


    }

    public void onStop() {

        super.onStop();

        saveBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();


    }

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    static final int REQUEST_GALLERY = 0;

    //create changeProfilePicture method and call it when the  ImageButton is pressed
    public void changeProfilePicture() {

// add alert dialog to ask user how they would like to change their profile icon



    }


    // override onActivityResult to allow the imageButton to be changed to picture taken from camera or gallery

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //create a switch based on requestCode
            switch (requestCode) {
                // if user clicks change profilePic through gallery use picture user picked from gallery
                case REQUEST_GALLERY:
                    Uri galleryImage = data.getData();
                    try {
                        Bitmap galleryBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), galleryImage);
                        galleryBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(galleryBitmap, 200, 200, false);
                        profilePic.setImageBitmap(galleryBitmap);
                       saveBitmap(galleryBitmap);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.i("TAG", "Exception " + e);
                    }

                    break;
                // if user clicks change profilePic through camera use picture user took from camera app

                case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:

                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                    imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, 200, 200, false);
                    profilePic.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                    saveBitmap(imageBitmap);

                    break;
            }

        }
    }



    private void saveBitmap(Bitmap bm){
        File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File newFile = new File(file, "myImage.jpg");

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i( "getExternalStorageDirectory", file.getPath()) ;
    }

    private void loadImageFromStorage(String path)
    {

        try {
            File f=new File(path, "myImage.jpg");
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            profilePic.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
                return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            }
        }

        if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }

    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions)
    {

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context!=null && permissions!=null){
            for(String permission: permissions){
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    return  false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}



// what I have for my ImageButton in xml

   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/profilePic"
        android:onClick="changeProfilePicture"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#0000"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
```

```
I have the following permissions inside the manifest.xml 

 <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am trying to save the new ImageButton from my result and load it when the app is relaunched. Can this be done with an ImageButton? Can it be saved to and loaded from a file?

Comment: You want to save the image of your imageButton when the app closes, and set that image back when the app is relaunched? Sorry I couldn't understand your question

Comment: Yes that's what I am trying to do. Sorry I couldn't think of how to say it.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to do something like that with an imageButton. You could use a imageView, set it on a oneClickListener and let it act as a imageButten. Everything is a Button if it has a onClickListener. Loading a image to a imageView is very easy :)

Comment: @newtoMobileDev I will try to answer this question with steps.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, you need to get the bitmap from the `imageButton` like this

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageButton.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Next you need to save this Bitmap to external storage like this

```
private void saveBitmap(Bitmap bm){
    File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File newFile = new File(file, "myImage.jpg");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And you load this saved bitmap like this

```
private void loadImageFromStorage(String path)
{

    try {
        File f=new File(path, "myImage.jpg");
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        imageButton.setImageBitmap(b);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
   {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

}
```

You should define the image path like this

```
String photoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myImage.jpg";
```

This is the main idea, you can add a bit of flavor into this code by setting a default image when there is no available image saved.

Hope this is what are looking for.

UPDATE:

You need to change this line

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageButton.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

To this

```
Drawable myDrawable = imageButton.getBackground();
```

After that you convert this `Drawable` to a `Bitmap`

```
Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(myDrawable);
```

Here is the function for this conversion

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    }

    if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

UPDATE 2 :

You need to request runtime permissions to save and retreive images
First you need to add this to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Next add this method to your activity

```
public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions)
{

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context!=null && permissions!=null){
        for(String permission: permissions){
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                return  false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Finally in your `onCreate` add those lines

```
int Permission_All = 1;

    String[] Permissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    if(!hasPermissions(this, Permissions)){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, Permissions, Permission_All);
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202081/discussion-on-answer-by-amine-how-to-save-new-imagebutton-picture-and-load-newly).